# Angular 2 Nested Component

Tags: angular

I am getting the following Error when i am developing an Angularjs 2 Application .

Step 1: I have Created a new Component

Step 2: I have added this component to app.module.ts

Step 3: Added  component to the Existing Markup .

Now I am getting the Following Error

[image]

Not able to find out the reason for the Error .

Here is the Code [Repository](https://github.com/vmurali100/angular2_error)

Comment: AngularJS (v1) and Angular 2 are two different frameworks. Also, try to be more specific by adding sample of your code.

Comment: Added Complete Git Repository

Comment: Please add the code and error message to your question

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is located in your static js file:

https://github.com/vmurali100/angular2_error/blob/master/dist/app.module.js#L20

It is not changed after running `npm start`

Add `tsconfig.json` to your project with the contents like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "outDir": "dist", // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  required
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And then you should able to update your static js files. **I don't understand why [they are in github repo](https://github.com/vmurali100/angular2_error/tree/master/dist).**

Comment: Try removing `dist` folder. It shoud be generated again

Comment: Can you check from your end . I am not able to figure it

Comment: How did you generate `dist` folder?